# Initialize ng-click value as true in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am working with a spa in angular, where I use ng-click to switch between pages (by showing and hiding divs). All works well, this is the simplified version of the code I am using:

```
<a href="" ng-click="first=true; second=false; third=false">First</a>
<a href="" ng-click="first=false; second=true; third=false">Second</a>
<a href="" ng-click="first=false; second=false; third=true">Third</a>

<div class="container" id='settings' ng-show='first'>   First  </div>
<div class="container" id='settings' ng-show='second'>  Second </div>
<div class="container" id='settings' ng-show='third'>    Third </div>
```

However, initially none of the divs is displayed - since none of the links is clicked. I would like the first page to show initially, and then hide if another link is clicked. How could I do that?

Comment: Define `first=true` in controller or in `ng-init`

Comment: @PankajParkar – I have mentioned that in my comment as well :)

Comment: @Rayon Sorry I completely missed that.. I refreshed comment later..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to propose little different solution combination of `ng-repeat` & `ng-switch` directive which suits perfectly for your case

**Code**

```
$scope.items = [
   {id: 1, name: 'First'},
   {id: 2, name: 'Second'},
   {id: 3, name: 'Third'},
];

$scope.model = { selected: 1};
```

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <a href="" ng-click="model.selected = item.id" ng-repeat="item in items">
   {{item.name}}
  </a>

  <div class="container" id='settings' ng-switch='model.selected'>
    <div ng-switch-when="1"> First </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="2"> Second </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="3"> Third </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/xizFyaDAWIhVL3Sii5BL?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize it either in view or controller, here is how you can do that in the view

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-init="first=true">
  <a href="" ng-click="first=true; second=false; third=false">First</a>
  <a href="" ng-click="first=false; second=true; third=false">Second</a>
  <a href="" ng-click="first=false; second=false; third=true">Third</a>

  <div class="container" id='settings' ng-show='first'>   First  </div>
  <div class="container" id='settings' ng-show='second'>  Second </div>
  <div class="container" id='settings' ng-show='third'>    Third </div>
</body>
```

but as suggested by the comments and the angular docs you should prefer to initialize it in the controller.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.first = true;
});

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <a href="" ng-click="first=true; second=false; third=false">First</a>
  <a href="" ng-click="first=false; second=true; third=false">Second</a>
  <a href="" ng-click="first=false; second=false; third=true">Third</a>

  <div class="container" id='settings' ng-show='first'>   First  </div>
  <div class="container" id='settings' ng-show='second'>  Second </div>
  <div class="container" id='settings' ng-show='third'>    Third </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is not what ng-init is for and it states such in the docs

Comment: Thanks for the info @charlietfl , i read the document https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit . It do say to use it with cautions.

Answer (score 1):

Define `first=true` in `ng-init` so that you do not have to change your controller. But, I will suggest you to initialize it in `controller`

Also note that you must define other `scope` variables as `false` in controller becuase right now they are `undefined(falsey)` which is the reason code is executing as expected but defining it will make it more readable.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.first = true;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <a href="" ng-click="first=true; second=false; third=false">First</a>
  <a href="" ng-click="first=false; second=true; third=false">Second</a>
  <a href="" ng-click="first=false; second=false; third=true">Third</a>

  <div class="container" id='settings' ng-show='first'>First</div>
  <div class="container" id='settings' ng-show='second'>Second</div>
  <div class="container" id='settings' ng-show='third'>Third</div>
</div>
```

**Using `ng-init`**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-init="first = true">

  <a href="" ng-click="first=true; second=false; third=false">First</a>
  <a href="" ng-click="first=false; second=true; third=false">Second</a>
  <a href="" ng-click="first=false; second=false; third=true">Third</a>

  <div class="container" id='settings' ng-show='first'>First</div>
  <div class="container" id='settings' ng-show='second'>Second</div>
  <div class="container" id='settings' ng-show='third'>Third</div>
</div>
```